# Set identifiers for reusable tableViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ui-testing

The tableViewCell contains two labels and the contents of the label are updated in each iteration. For UI testing, I need to set identifier of the labels to check if the content of the labels are same as those expected or not.
**How can I set identifiers for the labels inside the reusable cell dynamically?**

```
@interface MyDetailsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDLabel *myDetailsTitlelabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDLabel *myDetailsContentLabel;

@end
```

These are the two labels inside my tableViewCell.

Comment: try to associate tag with label and cell

Comment: show your design, that you want to achieve with table list.

Comment: try using `accessibilityIdentifier` property like this `label.accessibilityIdentifier = "label1"`

Comment: But can I dynamically change the identifier for each iteration using this property?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your tableView all set up and working.

In your `cellForRowAt` function you can set your Ids dynamically for each row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<your_reuse_identifier>", for: indexPath) as! MyDetailsTableViewCell
    cell.myDetailsTitlelabel.text = "id" // set your label text here    
    cell.myDetailsTitlelabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "id" // set your dynamic id here
    cell.myDetailsContentLabel.text = "id" // set your label text here    
    cell.myDetailsContentLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "id" // set your dynamic id here
    return cell
}
```